# Django internal server error on change of one line

Tags: django

I'm trying to set up a Django server on my Rpi, and got to the point where I could get to the admin page through nginx, based on these two tutorials;
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04
and 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/

My directory structure looks like this;

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/myproject $ ls
manage.py  myproject  myprojectenv  myproject.sock  polls  static

pi@raspberrypi:~/myproject $ ls polls
admin.py  apps.py  __init__.py  migrations  models.py  tests.py  urls.py views.py  views.py.save

pi@raspberrypi:~/myproject $ ls myproject
__init__.py  __pycache__  settings.py  urls.py  wsgi.py
```

Created an app called Polls from within the above directory.
    ./manage.py startapp polls

I've set the following in ~/myproject/myproject/settings.py

```
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost','127.0.0.1','192.168.1.213','*']
```

I've restarted nginx and gunicorn after each change.
I've tried moving ~/myproject/polls to ~/myproject/myproject/polls

The line that causes the internal server error is this in ~/myproject/myproject/urls.py;

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),#This one causes the internal server error.
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

I'm not really sure where to go from here, but suspect I'm close, any advice, suggestions or things I should be reading appreciated.

EDIT- James I got this when I ran the server as you suggested.
Ah, I get this when I start the server using you runserver command;,

```
  File "/home/pi/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/pi/myproject/myproject/urls.py", line 20, in <module>
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
NameError: name 'include' is not defined
```

Comment: Can you provide the full stack trace? You may need to configure gunicorn to write a server log (`--error-logfile FILE` I believe will do it). If you can't do it with gunicorn, does this app work using the development server (`python manage.py runserver`)?

Comment: Had to place reply to this under the main message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error says, you haven't defined `include`. You need to import it from the same place you do `url`:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
```